# Updating the mask style on a text box for time

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

I am really new to all Silverlight and just learning by example and looking at code, so sorry if it is a dumb question.
I have this style for showing times in XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="MyTimeMaskStyle" TargetType="controls:MyMaskedTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyMaskedTextBoxStyle}">
    <Setter Property="MaskType" Value="Standard" />
    <Setter Property="Mask" Value="##:## ll"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Placeholder" Value=" " />
</Style>
```

And it shows times in a format like **`05:34 PM`**
The problem is if data that is being loaded from the database(some old data) is originally saved in a format like **5:34 PM** then it will show it that way, notice it is missing that **"0"** before **5**?
So I need to modify this mask to make it always show that leading "0" too.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following `StringFormat` instead (assuming that that `MaskedTextBox` is using a `StringFormat`):

```
<Setter Property="Mask" Value="00:00 ll" />
```

The `#` character is an 'any character' placeholder, whereas the `0` character *should* display a `0` if there is no other value in that space. You can find out more from the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

However, if the value coming from the database is a `string`, then a `StringFormat` cannot be applied.

---

UPDATE >>>

I just realised that I linked to the wrong page on MSDN for the zero placeholder... you can find that in the [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN. I'll leave the other link because it's useful.

Ok, so I can only assume that the `MaskedTextBox` doesn't use plain `StringFormat` then... I guess that you're using it for a particular reason, but if you can just use a `TextBlock`, you should be able to display the time in the way that you want like this (if it is an actual `DateTime` instance):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding YourTimeProperty, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm tt}}" />
```

This should provide you with an output like you wanted: `05:34 PM`

Comment: will try it now, thanks. Also is there a good reference for all these masks ?

Comment: I just added one to my answer.

Comment: Thanks but it gives compile errors as soon as I add that StringFormat thing.